# functionName`string` - what does the syntax work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If you use [style-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) for reactjs, you'll find this type of syntax.

```
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;
```

Another reference: [CSSjs](https://github.com/rtsao/csjs)

```
const styles = csjs`
  .panel {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: ${green};
  }`;
```

My Question : How this type of syntax works?

---

If the syntax look like this (below), it's okay, I can understand that - it is a factory function that take one string parameter.

```
 const styles = csjs(`
  .panel {
        border: 1px solid black;
   }
 `)
```

---

But this syntax `functionName'string'` is looking really odd.